# Помогите с реализацией AutoCompleteTextView (скрывать и показывать выпадающий список по касанию в actv)

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Например имеется `AutoCompleteTextView actv`;

Нужно по каcанию на (`actv.setOnClickListener(...) ?`) вызывать выпадающий список `showDropDown();`, при следующем касании - скрывать, и так снова по кругу - при первом касании - вызывать, при следующем скрывать.
Данное касание должно выполняться только на actv.

Проблема в том, что как только касаешься actv, actv сразу делает dismiss выпадающего списка и отследить в нем - прошлое состояние выпадающего списка (скрытый или нет) невозможно...

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно что-то вроде этого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда будет примерно так:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
private EditText dateTime;
private String[] dateTimeList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dateTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.create_datetime);
        setListIcon(dateTime, dateTimeList);
    }

    private void setListIcon(EditText editText, String[] list) {
        if (list.length <= 1) {
            editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            editText.setOnTouchListener(null);
        } else {
            editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_menu_down, 0);
            editText.setOnTouchListener(new TouchListener());
        }
    }

private class TouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    private ListPopupWindow lpw;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
        final String[] list;

        if (v == dateTime) {
            list = dateTimeList;
        } else {
            list =null;
        }

        lpw = new ListPopupWindow(EditorActivity.this);
        lpw.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(EditorActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
        lpw.setAnchorView(v);
        lpw.setModal(true);
        lpw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String item = list[position];
                ((EditText) v).setText(item);
                v.setPressed(false);
                lpw.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (event.getX() >= (v.getWidth() - ((EditText) v)
                    .getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                lpw.show();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Разметка примерна такая

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/datetime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_menu_down"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_menu_down"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint=""
            android:inputType="datetime" >
        </EditText>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос был все таки об `AutoCompleteTextView`.
Просто боюсь что ваш голый `editText` не обеспечит должной функциональности, какая есть в `AutoCompleteTextView` (функционал выпадающего списка и прочее). Ставлю плюс, но пока еще подумаю, смогу ли я его применить в моей задаче...

Comment: Да, конечно. Я сам хотел сделать нечто, вроде вашей хотелки, но не нашел ничего подходящего, решил пожертвовать фичей автодополнения.